# '\\' and '\newline' not working

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

Those two symbols in the tite aren't working and I have no idea what's going on. This is my first time using latex so I'm lost. Also, can someone teach me how to `make a bullet like the one in Microsoft Word`? Here's my text:

```
%% logical symbols
% \land     /\
% \lor      \/
% \lnor     (negation)
% \to       ->
% \lequiv   <->
% \models   |=

...

\begin{solution}
$$(P \to (\lnot Q \land R)) \land (P \to \lnot Q)$$
$${With: \hspace{1cm} (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (\lnot P \lor R) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)}$$
$${ 
Without : T1 \lequiv T2 \land T4 \\
– T2 \lequiv P \to T3 \\
– T3 \lequiv \lnot Q \land R \\
– T4 \lequiv P \to \lnot Q \\
– F1 : (T1 \land T2 \land T4) \lor (\lnot T1 \land :T2) \lor (\lnot T1 \land \lnot T4) \\
– F2 : (T2 \land \lnot P) \lor (T2 \land T3) \lor (\lnot T2 \land P \land \lnot T3) \\
– F3 : (T3 \land \lnot Q \land R) \lor (\lnot T3 \land Q) \lor (\lnot T3 \land \lnot R) \\
– F4 : (T4 \land \lnot P) \lor (T4 \land \lnot Q) \lor (\lnot T4 \land P \land Q) \\
Final result: T1 \land F1 \land F2 \land F3 \land F4 }$$
\end{solution}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages you use. (See also:  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Hmmm.... Welcome! LaTeX is a whole different thing than Word. I really advise (if you want to learn LaTeX) going here: https://www.learnlatex.org/ and spend a couple of hour there.  It will be time well spent and it will save a lot of time.

Comment: Regarding the "bullet": I guess, you could be interested in using the `itemize` environment. (`\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}`). To customize such a list, take a look at the `enumitem` package.

Comment: More to the point, in math mode (and you shouldn't use `$$` in LaTeX anyway) newlines are ignored. And you are mixing an enumerating list and a formula. So it's better to go a bit back to the basics! Good luck!

Comment: @Rmano My teaching assistant use $$ symbol, if not it wont compile corectly

Comment: Regarding the use of `$$`, you might want to take a look at: [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/134144)

Comment: Since I have quite a hard time imagining how the output should look like, just based on the code you posted, please prepare a sketch of the expected output and add it to your question.

Comment: `$$` is not latex but if you do use it it is essentially `\[...\]` and that is a single line display, you can not use `\\ ` use `amsmath` package and an `align` enviornment for multi-line displays.

Answer (score 1):

`$$` is not latex syntax, but if you do use it it is essentially the same as `\[...\]` and that is a single line display, you can not use `\\`  to get multiple lines.

Use the `amsmath` package and an `align` or similar enviornment for multi-line displays.

It was rather hard to guess the intended layout but something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand\lequiv{\iff}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&(P \to (\lnot Q \land R)) \land (P \to \lnot Q)\\
\text{With}:&\, (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (\lnot P \lor R) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)\\
\text{Without}:&\, T1 \lequiv T2 \land T4 \\
&\,T2 \lequiv P \to T3 \\
&\,T3 \lequiv \lnot Q \land R \\
&\,T4 \lequiv P \to \lnot Q \\
F1 :&\, (T1 \land T2 \land T4) \lor (\lnot T1 \land :T2) \lor (\lnot T1 \land \lnot T4) \\
F2 :&\, (T2 \land \lnot P) \lor (T2 \land T3) \lor (\lnot T2 \land P \land \lnot T3) \\
 F3 :&\, (T3 \land \lnot Q \land R) \lor (\lnot T3 \land Q) \lor (\lnot T3 \land \lnot R) \\
F4 :&\,(T4 \land \lnot P) \lor (T4 \land \lnot Q) \lor (\lnot T4 \land P \land Q) \\
\text{Final result}:&\, T1 \land F1 \land F2 \land F3 \land F4 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```